# gethitRect() , I am doing it wrong, how does this work?

Tags: android, image

I keep getting `top, bottom, left, right = 0`.  I guess I am doing this wrong, what is the correct way? TIA

in `onCreate()`

```
    ImageView trash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dropTarget_trash);
    trash.setOnTouchListener(this);
    Rect trashHit = new Rect();
    trash.getHitRect(trashHit);
    Log.d(TAG,"Trash left:" + trashHit.left + " right: " + trashHit.right + "  top: " + trashHit.top + " bottom: " + trashHit.bottom);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the hit rect is in the parent coordinate space, the parent first needs to layout its children which it hasn't done yet during `onCreate()`.  Take a look at the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343222/is-there-an-example-of-how-to-use-a-touchdelegate-in-android-to-increase-the-size) for an example of running in `post()`.  If you have a custom view, `getHitRect()` within `onDraw()` will give you the correct dimensions too.