# How can check the intersection two image android?

Tags: android, rect

I have two images and i want check the intersection that. But my code not working!
Please, help me!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView img1, img2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onWindowFocusChanged(true);
    AddEvents();
}
public void Form(){
    img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
}

public void AddEvents(){
    Form();
    Rect r1= new Rect();
    img1.getHitRect(r1);
    Rect r2= new Rect();
    img2.getHitRect(r2);
    if(Rect.intersects(r1,r2)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "intersected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How do you know it is not working ? What happens ?

Comment: Toast is not show :(

Comment: Does they intersect in layout? Could you please show your activity_main.xml?

Comment: this xml capture at link: https://www.mediafire.com/?73yv6z78fiyftb7

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you are doing it correctly and they do NOT intersect:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersects(android.graphics.Rect, android.graphics.Rect)

The problem is that `getHitRect` is probably not doing what you expect it to do. It is designed to make the "hit" area (touch area) a different size than the object. Also, if you check it before the layout is done, it will not return anything useful.

See this post:

[gethitRect() , I am doing it wrong, how does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933787/gethitrect-i-am-doing-it-wrong-how-does-this-work)