# How To Use Multiple TouchDelegate

Tags: android, layout, view, imagebutton

i have two ImageButtons, each inside a RelativeLayout and these two RelativeLayouts are in another RelativeLayout, i want to set TouchDelegate for each ImageButton. If normally i add TouchDelegate to each ImageButton and it's parent RelativeLayout then just one ImageButton works properly, Another one doesn't extend it's clicking area. So PLease help me on how to use TouchDelegate in both ImageButtons. If it's not possible then what can be a effective way to extend the clicking area of a view? Thanks in advance ........

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/FrameContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="113dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/tutorial1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null" android:src="@drawable/tutorial" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2" android:layout_width="113dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip" android:layout_marginLeft="100dip">
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/tutorial2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null" android:src="@drawable/tutorial"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity class :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.TouchDelegate;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestTouchDelegate extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View mParent1 = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    mParent1.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect bounds1 = new Rect();
            ImageButton mTutorialButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
            mTutorialButton1.setEnabled(true);
            mTutorialButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(TestTouchDelegate.this, "Test TouchDelegate 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            mTutorialButton1.getHitRect(bounds1);
            bounds1.right += 50;
            TouchDelegate touchDelegate1 = new TouchDelegate(bounds1, mTutorialButton1);

            if (View.class.isInstance(mTutorialButton1.getParent())) {
                ((View) mTutorialButton1.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate1);
            }
        }
    });

    //View mParent = findViewById(R.id.FrameContainer);
    View mParent2 = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
    mParent2.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect bounds2 = new Rect();
            ImageButton mTutorialButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tutorial2);
            mTutorialButton2.setEnabled(true);
            mTutorialButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(TestTouchDelegate.this, "Test TouchDelegate 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            mTutorialButton2.getHitRect(bounds2);
            bounds2.left += 50;
            TouchDelegate touchDelegate2 = new TouchDelegate(bounds2, mTutorialButton2);

            if (View.class.isInstance(mTutorialButton2.getParent())) {
                ((View) mTutorialButton2.getParent()).setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate2);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 31):

You can use composite pattern to be able to add more than one `TouchDelegate` to the `View`. Steps:

1. Create `TouchDelegateComposite` (no matter what view you'll pass as an
   argument, it's used just to get the Context)
2. Create necessary `TouchDelegates` and add them to composite
3. Add composite to view as they recommend [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/04/15/android-using-touchdelegates/) (via `view.post(new Runnable)`)

   ```
   public class TouchDelegateComposite extends TouchDelegate {

       private final List<TouchDelegate> delegates = new ArrayList<TouchDelegate>();
       private static final Rect emptyRect = new Rect();

       public TouchDelegateComposite(View view) {
           super(emptyRect, view);
       }

       public void addDelegate(TouchDelegate delegate) {
           if (delegate != null) {
               delegates.add(delegate);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           boolean res = false;
           float x = event.getX();
           float y = event.getY();
           for (TouchDelegate delegate : delegates) {
               event.setLocation(x, y);
               res = delegate.onTouchEvent(event) || res;
           }
           return res;
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: This is a much better solution, not cluttered view hierarchy full of wrapper views, or messing with padding, and no need for subclassing views to override the getHitRect() method. One minor suggestion would be to incorporate the expandTouchArea() method from @Brendan Weinstein's answer into this class for the sake of neatness/ease.

Comment: I adapted this solution to expand the clickable area of views with the same parent: [gist](https://gist.github.com/nikosk/3854f2effe65438cfa40)

@AndroidNoob: included a static method for ease of use. Used like this:  TouchDelegateComposite.expandClickArea(buttonView, parentView, clickListener, paddingInDP);

Comment: This does not answer OPs question. OP is not trying to add multiple delegates to one view. The two ``ImageButton``s in OPs example have *different* parents.

Comment: Yes, the answer is you cannot.

Answer (score 5):

There is only supposed to be one touch delegate for each view.  The documentation for getTouchDelegate() in the View class reads:

"Gets the TouchDelegate for this View."

There is only to be one TouchDelegate.  To use only one TouchDelegate per view, you can wrap each touchable view within a view with dimensions reflecting what you would like to be touchable.  An android developer at square gives an example of how you can do this for multiple Views using just one static method (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF6Ad4GYjRU&t=37m4s):

```
  public static void expandTouchArea(final View bigView, final View smallView, final int extraPadding) {
bigView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        smallView.getHitRect(rect);
        rect.top -= extraPadding;
        rect.left -= extraPadding;
        rect.right += extraPadding;
        rect.bottom += extraPadding;
        bigView.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, smallView));
    }
});
```

}

Let's say that you do not want to clutter your view hierarchy.  There are two other options I can think of.  You can define the bounds of what is touchable inside the touchable view and make sure to pass all touchevents to that child view from respective parent views.  Or you can override getHitRect() for the touchable view.  The former will quickly clutter your code and make it difficult to understand, so the latter is the better way forward.  You want to go with overriding getHitRect.

Where mPadding is the amount of extra area you want to be touchable around your view, you could use something like the following:

```
    @Override
public void getHitRect(Rect outRect) {
    outRect.set(getLeft() - mPadding, getTop() - mPadding, getRight() + mPadding, getTop() + mPadding);
}
```

If you use code like the above you'll have to consider what touchable views are nearby.  The touchable area of the View that is highest on the stack could overlap on top of another View.

Another similar option would be to just change the padding of the touchable view.  I dislike this as a solution because it can become difficult to keep track of how Views are being resized.

Comment: I tried to override the getHitRect but it doesn't seem to work (it doesn't get called at all). Basically I create a custom view which extends a ImageButton then in the class I override the getHitRect (with added padding) but as I mentioned, getHitRect never get called. Is it possible to post your solution?

Comment: It turns out the solution I offered does not work in ICS, that might be why it's not working for you.  I wrote a blog post on two different Touch Delegate strategies http://www.brendanweinstein.me/2012/06/26/touchdelegate-and-gethitrect-making-buttons-with-expanded-touch-areas/ and you can get sample code for both strategies at https://github.com/brendanw/Touch-Delegates/blob/master/src/com/brendan/touchdelegates/MyTouchDelegate.java

Comment: This does not answer OPs question. OP is not trying to add multiple delegates to one view. The two ``ImageButton``s in OPs example have *different* parents.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin version of @need1milliondollars's answer:

```
class TouchDelegateComposite(view: View) : TouchDelegate(Rect(), view) {

    private val delegates: MutableList<TouchDelegate> = ArrayList()

    fun addDelegate(delegate: TouchDelegate) {
        delegates.add(delegate)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        var res = false
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        for (delegate in delegates) {
            event.setLocation(x, y)
            res = delegate.onTouchEvent(event) || res
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fully working Kotlin extension function which allows for multiple views to increase their touch target by the same amount:

```
// Example of usage
parentLayout.increaseHitAreaForViews(views = *arrayOf(myFirstView, mySecondView, myThirdView))

/*
 * Use this function if a parent view contains more than one view that
 * needs to increase its touch target hit area.
 *
 * Call this on the parent view
 */
fun View.increaseHitAreaForViews(@DimenRes radiusIncreaseDpRes: Int = R.dimen.touch_target_default_radius_increase, vararg views: View) {
    val increasedRadiusPixels = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(radiusIncreaseDpRes)
    val touchDelegateComposite = TouchDelegateComposite(this)
    post {
        views.forEach { view ->
            val rect = Rect()
            view.getHitRect(rect)
            rect.top -= increasedRadiusPixels
            rect.left -= increasedRadiusPixels
            rect.bottom += increasedRadiusPixels
            rect.right += increasedRadiusPixels
            touchDelegateComposite.addDelegate(TouchDelegate(rect, view))
        }
        touchDelegate = touchDelegateComposite
    }
}

class TouchDelegateComposite(view: View) : TouchDelegate(Rect(), view) {
    private val delegates = mutableListOf<TouchDelegate>()

    fun addDelegate(delegate: TouchDelegate) {
        delegates.add(delegate)
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        var res = false
        for (delegate in delegates) {
            event.setLocation(event.x, event.y)
            res = delegate.onTouchEvent(event) || res
        }
        return res
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code working you need to decrease left border of `bounds2`, and not increase it.

```
bounds2.left -= 50;
```

After playing around with `TouchDelegate`, I came to the code below, which works for me all the time on any Android version. The trick is to extend area guarantied after layout is called.

```
public class ViewUtils {

    public static final void extendTouchArea(final View view, 
            final int padding) {

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                final Rect touchArea = new Rect();
                view.getHitRect(touchArea);
                touchArea.top -= padding;
                touchArea.bottom += padding;
                touchArea.left -= padding;
                touchArea.right += padding;

                final TouchDelegate touchDelegate = 
                    new TouchDelegate(touchArea, view);
                final View parent = (View) view.getParent();
                parent.setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);

                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this seemed to be working for me http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/02/16/listview-tips-tricks-5-enlarged-touchable-areas/

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i  guess nobody provides the real answer to make solution of it and make it easy.Lately i had same issue and reading all above i just had no clue how just to make it work.But finally i did it.First thing to keep in your mind!Lets pretend you have one whole layout which is holding your two small buttons which area must be expanded,so you MUST make another layout inside your main layout and put another button to your newly created layout so in that case with static method you can give touch delegate to 2 buttons at the same time.Now more deeply and step by step into code!
first you surely just find the view of your MAINLAYOUT and Button like this.(this layout will hold our first button)

```
RelativeLayout mymainlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mymainlayout)
Button mybutoninthislayout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton)
```

ok we done finding the main layout and its button  view which will hold everything its just our `onCreate()` displaying layout but you have to find in case to use it later.Ok what next?We create another RelativeLayout inside our main layout which width and height is on your taste(this newly created layout will hold our second button)

```
RelativeLayout myinnerlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myinnerlayout)
Button mybuttoninsideinnerlayout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mysecondbutton)
```

ok we done finding views so we can now just copy and paste the code of our guy who firstly answered your question.Just copy that code inside your main activity.

```
 public static void expandTouchArea(final View bigView, final View smallView, final int extraPadding) {
    bigView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            smallView.getHitRect(rect);
            rect.top -= extraPadding;
            rect.left -= extraPadding;
            rect.right += extraPadding;
            rect.bottom += extraPadding;
            bigView.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, smallView));
        }
    });
}
```

Now how to use this method and make it work?here is how!
on your `onCreate()` method paste the next code snippet

```
  expandTouchArea(mymainlayout,mybutoninthislayout,60);
  expandTouchArea(myinnerlayout, mybuttoninsideinnerlayout,60);
```

Explanation on what we did in this snipped.We took our created static method named `expandTouchArea()` and gave 3 arguments.
1st argument-The layout which holds the button which area must be expanded
2nd argument - actual button to expand the area of it
3rd argument - the area in pixels of how much we want the button area to be expanded!
ENJOY!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: Trying to add multiple `TouchDelegates` for different `LinearLayouts` that route touch events to separate `Switches` respectively, in one layout.

For details please refer to [this question asked by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523242/struggeling-with-multiple-use-of-androids-touchdelegate) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523242/struggeling-with-multiple-use-of-androids-touchdelegate/46037777#46037777).

What I found is: Once I enclose the `LinearLayouts` each by **another** `LinearLayout`, respectively, the second (end every other successive) `TouchDelegate` starts to work as expected.

So this might help the OP to create a working solution to his problem.
I don't have a satisfying explanation on why it behaves like this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the code of TouchDelegate and made some alter. Now it can support multi Views regardless of whether thoese views had common parents

```
class MyTouchDelegate: TouchDelegate {
private var mDelegateViews = ArrayList<View>()

private var mBoundses = ArrayList<Rect>()

private var mSlopBoundses = ArrayList<Rect>()

private var mDelegateTargeted: Boolean = false

val ABOVE = 1
val BELOW = 2
val TO_LEFT = 4
val TO_RIGHT = 8

private var mSlop: Int = 0

constructor(context: Context): super(Rect(), View(context)) {
    mSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
}

fun addTouchDelegate(delegateView: View, bounds: Rect) {
    val slopBounds = Rect(bounds)
    slopBounds.inset(-mSlop, -mSlop)
    mDelegateViews.add(delegateView)
    mSlopBoundses.add(slopBounds)
    mBoundses.add(Rect(bounds))
}

var targetIndex = -1

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val x = event.x.toInt()
    val y = event.y.toInt()
    var sendToDelegate = false
    var hit = true
    var handled = false


    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            targetIndex = -1

            for ((index, item) in mBoundses.withIndex()) {
                if (item.contains(x, y)) {
                    mDelegateTargeted = true
                    targetIndex = index
                    sendToDelegate = true
                }
            }
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            sendToDelegate = mDelegateTargeted
            if (sendToDelegate) {
                val slopBounds = mSlopBoundses[targetIndex]
                if (!slopBounds.contains(x, y)) {
                    hit = false
                }
            }
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
            sendToDelegate = mDelegateTargeted
            mDelegateTargeted = false
        }
    }
    if (sendToDelegate) {
        val delegateView = mDelegateViews[targetIndex]

        if (hit) {
            // Offset event coordinates to be inside the target view
            event.setLocation((delegateView.width / 2).toFloat(), (delegateView.height / 2).toFloat())
        } else {
            // Offset event coordinates to be outside the target view (in case it does
            // something like tracking pressed state)
            val slop = mSlop
            event.setLocation((-(slop * 2)).toFloat(), (-(slop * 2)).toFloat())
        }
        handled = delegateView.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
    return handled
}
```

}

use it like this

```
  fun expandTouchArea(viewList: List<View>, touchSlop: Int) {


    val rect = Rect()

    viewList.forEach {
        it.getHitRect(rect)
        if (rect.left == rect.right && rect.top == rect.bottom) {
            postDelay(Runnable { expandTouchArea(viewList, touchSlop) }, 200)
            return
        }
        rect.top -= touchSlop
        rect.left -= touchSlop
        rect.right += touchSlop
        rect.bottom += touchSlop

        val parent = it.parent as? View
        if (parent != null) {
            val parentDelegate = parent.touchDelegate
            if (parentDelegate != null) {
                (parentDelegate as? MyTouchDelegate)?.addTouchDelegate(it, rect)
            } else {
                val touchDelegate = MyTouchDelegate(this)
                touchDelegate.addTouchDelegate(it, rect)
                parent.touchDelegate = touchDelegate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a simple solution from the link that Brendan Weinstein listed above - the static method was incredibly clean and tidy compared to all other solutions.  Padding for me simply doesnt work.

My use case was increasing the touch area of 2 small buttons to improve UX.

I have a `MyUserInterfaceManager` class, where i insert the static function from the [youtube video](https://youtu.be/jF6Ad4GYjRU?t=2222);

```
public static void changeViewsTouchArea(final View newTouchArea, 
                                        final View viewToChange) {
    newTouchArea.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect(0,0, newTouchArea.getWidth(), newTouchArea.getHeight());       
            newTouchArea.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(rect, viewToChange));
        }
    });
}
```

Then in XML i have the following code (per imagebutton);

```
<!-- constrain touch area to button / view!-->
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/btn_a_touch_area"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/large_touch_area"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/large_touch_area"
/>

<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_id_here"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size" />
```

The in the `onCreateView(...)` method of my fragment i called the method per `View` that needs the touch area modified (after binding both `Views`!);

```
MyUserInterfaceManager.changeViewsTouchArea(buttonATouchArea, buttonA);

buttonA.setOnClickListener(v -> {
   // add event code here
});
```

This solution means i can explicitly design and see the touch area in layout files - a must have to ensure im not getting too close to other `View` touch areas (compared to the "calculate and add pixels" methods recommended by google and others).