# Struggling with multiple use of Androids TouchDelegate

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, touch, android-view

I have a layout with a root element `LinearLayout` which encloses two other `LinearLayouts`, which make up for two rows. Those contain a `Switch` respectively.

In reality it looks somewhat like this: [example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaHGG.png)

This is how my example layout file  looks like:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_row_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Switch android:id="@+id/switch_row_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_row_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Switch android:id="@+id/switch_row_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, what I want to accomplish is, that touching the area of the first `LinearLayout` will trigger the first `Switch` and touching the area of the second `LinearLayout` will trigger the second `Switch`.

As explained in [Is there an example of how to use a TouchDelegate in Android to increase the size of a view's click target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343222) and [How To Use Multiple TouchDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799066) I used a TouchDelegate to increase the touchable area of the `Switch` to its parent `View`, the `LinearLayout`.

Here is my method for that:

```
public static void expandTouchArea(final View smallView, final View largeView) {
largeView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
                largeView.getHitRect(delegateArea);
                TouchDelegate delegate = new TouchDelegate(delegateArea, smallView);
                largeView.setTouchDelegate(delegate);
            }
        });
}
```

In my `onCreate()` I call it for both rows:

```
mLayoutRow1 = findViewById(R.id.layout_row_1);
mLayoutRow2 = findViewById(R.id.layout_row_2);

mSwitchRow1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_row_1);
mSwitchRow2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_row_2);

expandTouchArea(mSwitchRow1, mLayoutRow1);
expandTouchArea(mSwitchRow2, mLayoutRow2);
```

What I cannot understand is, that for row 1 it is working, but for row 2 (and any other successive calls to `expandTouchArea`) it does NOT work.

I also tried to instead of adding the `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, post a `Runnable` to the event message queue of the `Switch` itself, resulting in exactly the same behavior.

So the **question** I could not answer so far is: Is it possible to have multiple `TouchDelegates` for different `LinearLayouts` that route touch events to separate `Switches` respectively, in one layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when I add another `LinearLayout` around each row, both `TouchDelegates` work.

Now my example layout file looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_row_1"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Switch android:id="@+id/switch_row_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_row_2"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Switch android:id="@+id/switch_row_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe there is another solution. This one seems somehow tedious.