# Strange behavior when enlarging rectangle for TouchDelegate

Tags: android

I tend to increase top area of a hit rectangle.

I refer to the code found in [Is there an example of how to use a TouchDelegate in Android to increase the size of a view's click target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343222/is-there-an-example-of-how-to-use-a-touchdelegate-in-android-to-increase-the-siz) and http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate

```
final View parentView = v.findViewById(R.id.touch_delegate_linear_layout);
ViewTreeObserver vto = parentView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        final Rect r = new Rect();
        // currencyExchangeLinearLayout is currency_exchange_linear_layout.xml
        currencyExchangeLinearLayout.getHitRect(r);
        r.top -= 10;
        parentView.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(r , currencyExchangeLinearLayout));

        ViewTreeObserver obs = parentView.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

`touch_delegate_linear_layout` is my parent view.

`currency_exchange_linear_layout` is my touched target.

Here's how my layout looks like

[image]

The XML code for the above layout is as follow.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/touch_delegate_linear_layout"
    ...>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_linear_layout"
        ...
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_label_text_view"
            ... />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_value_text_view"
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        ...
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/status_bar"
            ... />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/currency_exchange_linear_layout"
            ...>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works perfectly fine, if I touch within the area of `currency_exchange_linear_layout`

[image]

I expect the touch will work too, even I touch slightly above `currency_exchange_linear_layout`. This is because I have code `r.top -= 10;` to expand my touch area. **However, it doesn't work as expected.**

[image]

The strange part is, if I touch far from `currency_exchange_linear_layout`, the touch event will be mistakenly triggered. This is not what I'm expecting.

[image]

Any idea why such strange behavior occur? Is there anything wrong with my `TouchDelegate` code?

### Demo Code

Here's the sample code, which uses to demonstrate the mentioned problem : https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wzu2w5dtpu6z5o/MyApplication2.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of this such behavior, is due to the fact `currency_exchange_linear_layout` is **NOT direct child** of `touch_delegate_linear_layout`

Hence, when we perform

```
currencyExchangeLinearLayout.getHitRect(r);
```

The obtained rectangle's coordinate is not relative to `touch_delegate_linear_layout`

In such case, we may use `footer_value_text_view`'s hit rectangle, which its rectangle's Y-coordinate is relative to `touch_delegate_linear_layout`

```
final View parentView = v.findViewById(R.id.touch_delegate_linear_layout);
final View directChildView = v.findViewById(R.id.footer_value_text_view);

ViewTreeObserver vto = parentView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        final Rect r = new Rect();
        final Rect directChild = new Rect();

        currencyExchangeLinearLayout.getHitRect(r);
        directChildView.getHitRect(directChild);

        int bestHeight = Utils.dpToPixel(48);

        directChild.top = directChild.bottom - Math.max((bestHeight - r.height()), 0);

        parentView.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(directChild, currencyExchangeLinearLayout));

        ViewTreeObserver obs = parentView.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```