# Expand TouchDelegate beyond view's parent

Tags: android

I have a layout that looks like this:

[image]

and I am trying to expand clickable area for the green view. The code that I use for this purpose is:

```
public static void setTouchDelegate(View view, float dimen) {
    final View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    parent.post( () -> {
        final Rect delegateArea = new Rect();
        view.getHitRect(delegateArea);
        delegateArea.right += dimen;
        delegateArea.left -= dimen;
        delegateArea.bottom += dimen;
        delegateArea.top -= dimen;

        parent.setTouchDelegate( new TouchDelegate( delegateArea , view));
    });
}
```

The red area is the parent of the green view. The problem is that regardless how large TouchDelegate I am trying to set it always applies only within the parent, the red area. I can cover the whole red area to be clickable but I can't expand the clickable area into the blue area.

My assumption is that this is not a problem in my code but normal behaviour of TouchDelegate.

The question is: how can I set clickable area for the green view that looks like the purple area on the following preview ?

[image]

// edit:

This is layout of the item - the red rectangle with text and the green ImageButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="18dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:text="Test" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_green"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you can create overlay over it

Comment: @VivekMishra I've edited my post. Do you mean an overlay for the green ImageButton ? If yes, how can I do that without expanding my top FrameLayout ? because if I change size of the FrameLayout then it is something, of course, that breaks the rest of the layout outside.

Comment: How about a transparent view ?

Comment: How can I add an transparent view that is bigger than the red area without expanding size of my overall item size (by item I mean the red element on the blue background) ? //edit You know, if I change the item size then I break my layout outside. lets assume that I want to have many of these items next to each other without having space between them.

Comment: I have added an answer. Try it once

Comment: tried `grandParent.setTouchDelegate()` ?

Comment: @pskink yes and also various variations and various settings of delegate area with that. But I could never touch further than beyond the red area or touch delegate disappeared at all.

Comment: I've tried to set TouchDelegate on gradparent, and it worked. The issue might be that you need to traverse a bit further into ancestors' hierarchy, as direct grandparent might still be a small view. Use AS Layout Inspector in Tools Menu to inspect your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to set the delegateArea relative to the view' ancestor, and set the TouchDelegate on this ancestor.

In your image the target ancestor is the view with the blue background.

```
fun getRelativeLeft(view: View?, ancestor: View) : Int {
    if (view == null)
        return 0
    return if (view.parent == ancestor)
        view.left
    else
        view.left + getRelativeLeft(view.parent as? View, ancestor)
}

fun getRelativeTop(view: View?, ancestor: View) : Int {
    if (view == null)
        return 0
    return if (view.parent == ancestor)
        view.top
    else
        view.top + getRelativeTop(view.parent as? View, ancestor)
}


val relativeTop = Point(getRelativeLeft(view, ancestorView), getRelativeTop(view, ancestorView))

// View area in ancestor coordinates
val relativeRc = Rect(relativeTop.x, relativeTop.y, relativeTop.x + view.width, relativeTop.y + view.height) 

// Increase touch area
relativeRc.inset(-offsetWidth, -offsetHeight)

// Set touch delegate on ancestorView with target view
ancestorView.touchDelegate = TouchDelegate(relativeRc, view)
```

Also it is better to use the modified TouchDelegate, due to a bug in  the original version https://gist.github.com/patrickhammond/6d49e9ac08f96bd8d302#gistcomment-2385782

Comment: Hi @southerton, I'm not familiar with Kotlin so how's possible that if view != ancestor in the getRelative method cannot become a recursive call like in Java? 
Thanks!